# How to configure aws codebuild with private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, aws-codebuild

I am setting up AWS codebuild and i am able to build successfully if i connect public RDS in application and no VPC configuration to codebuild.

Security reason i have created a private RDS to the application and configured the VPC in codebuild but i am getting while validating VPC configuration in codebuild

```
The VPC with ID vpc-XXXX might not have an internet connection. 
CodeBuild cannot find the 0.0.0.0/0 destination for the target 
internet gateway with subnet ID subnet-XXXXX.
```

VPC having two subnets( subnet1 and subnet2)

"Subnet1(public) has application and route table is as below"

```
0.0.0.0/0 - internet gateway
Associated to subnet1
```

"Subnet2(private) has rds and route table is as below"

```
0.0.0.0/0 - NAT gateway(subnet2)
Associated to subnet2
```

I have created the RDS using subnet2.

"Codebuild vpc configuration has below"

```
VPC - VPC-XXXX
Subnet - subnet2(private)
```

Comment: I have solved the issue by changing NAT gateway to public subnet instead of private subnet

Comment: Great. Were the troubleshooting steps in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/vpc-support.html#troubleshooting-vpc helpful? Also, instead of using a NAT Gateway, you may also using a proxy server in your public subnet. Documentation @ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/use-proxy-server.html